# Custom Follow People function from Search Site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, search, user-profile

For various reasons I need a function that follows people from "people search results". Like the Sharepoint hover has a follow link, I need the same, but I need a function that I can use on each search result. So on each click it must check if this person is followed and follow if not and unfollow if allready followed.